How to run tests on a .dll file using the DotNetCoreCLI@2 command?
I'm facing an annoying issue with running tests in my YAML pipeline. The setup is as follows:
I have an Azure Functions project, for example, Users, which also has an xUnit test project, :Users.Tests. In the CI stage, unit tests are run using the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task. After that, the projects are built and published as artifacts, archived as Users.zip and Users.Tests.zip, and stored in the drop and drop-tests folders.
Once the CI stage is complete, the CD stage begins. The idea is to download the archived function zip file and deploy it using the AzureFunctionApp@1 task. After the deployment is complete, I want to download the Users.Tests.zip file and run workflow tests, which make requests to the newly deployed Azure Functions.
This flow is almost completed and this is how the running workflow tests task looks like:
      - task: ExtractFiles@1
        displayName: 'Extract function test package'
        inputs:
          archiveFilePatterns: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.pipelineName}}/drop-tests/${{testsPackage}}.zip'
          destinationFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/workflow-tests'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Run workflow tests'
        env:
          ProjectId: $(WorkflowTestsProjectId)
          OrganizationId: $(WorkflowTestsOrganizationId)
          AccessKeyId: $(WorkflowTestsAccessKeyId)
          AccessKeySecret: $(WorkflowTestsAccessKeySecret)
        inputs:
          command: test
          projects: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.pipelineName}}/drop-tests/${{testsPackage}}.dll'
          publishTestResults: true
          arguments: >-
            -c Release
            --filter Category=WorkflowTest
            --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" 
            -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura

The files are extracted, but when its try to run the tests, the command line throws this exception:

Testhost process for source(s) '/agent/_work/5/s/workflow-tests/Users.Tests.dll' exited with error: Cannot use file stream for [/agent/_work/5/s/workflow-tests/Users.Tests.runtimeconfig.json]: Permission denied.


Invalid runtimeconfig.json [/agent/_work/5/s/workflow-tests/Users.Tests.runtimeconfig.json] [/agent/_work/5/s/workflow-tests/Users.Tests.runtimeconfig.dev.json]

Also, I forgot to mention earlier, but I'm passing environment variables to the test projects, and I'm not entirely sure if these environment variables are being passed correctly, when targeting .dll.
Additionally, I tried using a script or another test command, but the result was the same.

There is a https://devops.stackexchange.com/, and while there is an overlap as this question doesn't really involve actual coding, it may rather belong to there.
